# Iron Router URL Extension

Tags: meteor, iron-router

So I have a user profile and would like to have a "Favorites" section linked to it where favorited posts are displayed.

My user profile URL looks like this in Iron Router:

```
path: '/:username'
```

And my "Favorites" URL looks like this:

```
path: '/:username/favorites'
```

And I'd like my user profile to have this:

```
<template name="userProfile">
   <a href={{pathFor 'favorites'}}>Favorites</a>
</template>
```

Is there a quick solution to essentially "extend" the user profile route by adding "/favorites" on to it? Would I need to use "Router.current().url" in a template helper, or is there an easier way?

Comment: I don't understand how `{{pathFor "favorites"}}` is not already what you're looking for ? If you want to access this in JS use `Router.path("favorites", Meteor.user())`

Comment: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters - look at the second example code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pathFor` helper takes the params for the URL from the context it is called from. So in your case it will search for `username` inside the `userProfile`-template instance. So there are two ways of going about this.

- You could add `username` to the data context
- Use a spacebars `with`-block

Here's the code using a `with`-block

```
{{ #with currentUser }}
  {{ pathFor 'favorites' }}
{{ /with }}
```

---

#### EDIT

[`currentUser`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser) is a global helper. It returns the current users data.

Comment: So could I pass the the username to the data context through the params? `data: function () { return { username: this.params.username }; } `

Comment: Well, yes you could. But the `currentUser` helper is available to you [in all templates](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentuser). It returns an object containing the current users username, his _id and more.